# Interpreting Poisson regression analysis

Tags: poisson-regression

I ran my data through R and got these results.
I wanted to ask about the meaning of the results. Could it be that one variable is not significant when looking at the entire model, but significant when analyzing Incidence Rate Ratios?

I am attaching the data as an example but this is a general question..

[image: Example]